# Slim Post Request, No Response Data

Tags: php, slim

I have the following code

```
$app->post('/return/', function() use($app){
    error_log($app->request()->params('data'));
    $res = $app->response;
    $res->setStatus(400);
    $res->write('You made a bad request');
    $res->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
});
```

The http request will succeed with status code 200, but i will get no response data and wondering if my SLIM code is working properly? I have no problems with simple ajax request to receive a response, only in the case of custom responses. Anyone got some suggestions?

Comment: What version of Slim are you using? What is the content of your `.htaccess`?

Comment: How are you trying to read the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$app->post('/return/', function() use($app){
    error_log($app->request()->params('data'));
    $res = $app->response;
    $res->setStatus(400);
    $res->setBody('You made a bad request');
    $res->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $res->finalize();
});
```